# Render multiple plots from from single dataset (shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I have shiny app where I upload the dataset, then manipulate the dataset and build pultiple plots from it. Right now I do the dataset manipulation in every renderPlot block, but it seems to me that there should be another way. Where should I put the dataset manipulation so I can only do it once and pass into the rendetPlot blocks?

Sample of my current situation:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("STAR",
             tabPanel("PromptHits",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          width = 2,
                          fileInput(inputId = "pHitsFile", label = "Upload Data File"),
                          actionButton("pHitsMake", "Analyze")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          h3("Prompt Hits [all]"),
                          plotlyOutput("pHits1", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotlyOutput("pHits2", width = 500, height = 500),
                          h3("Prompt Hits [outliers removed]"),
                          plotlyOutput("pHits3", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotlyOutput("pHits4", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotOutput("pHits5", width = 1000),
                          plotOutput("pHits6", width = 1000),
                          plotOutput("pHits7", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotOutput("pHits8", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotOutput("pHits9", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotOutput("pHits10", width = 500, height = 500)
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
  output$pHits1 <- renderPlotly(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pqi
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits2 <- renderPlotly(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pqo
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits3 <- renderPlotly(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pqci
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits4 <- renderPlotly(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pqco
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits5 <- renderPlot(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pqci_padrow
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits6 <- renderPlot(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pqco_padrow
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits7 <- renderPlot(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pqci_agg
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits8 <- renderPlot(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pqco_agg
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits9 <- renderPlot(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pfitd0
      }
    }
  )
  output$pHits10 <- renderPlot(
    {
      if (input$pHitsMake) {
        inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
        out$pfitd1
      }
    }
  )
}

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

I do not want to do:

```
inputData <- input$pHitsFile
        d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
        source("pHitsMaker.R")
        out <- pHits(d)
```

every time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`eventReactive`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html). With this, you can make a reactive expression for the plot data, that gets only updated when `input$pHitsmake` is clicked:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("STAR",
             tabPanel("PromptHits",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          width = 2,
                          fileInput(inputId = "pHitsFile", label = "Upload Data File"),
                          actionButton("pHitsMake", "Analyze")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          h3("Prompt Hits [all]"),
                          plotlyOutput("pHits1", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotlyOutput("pHits2", width = 500, height = 500),
                          h3("Prompt Hits [outliers removed]"),
                          plotlyOutput("pHits3", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotlyOutput("pHits4", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotOutput("pHits5", width = 1000),
                          plotOutput("pHits6", width = 1000),
                          plotOutput("pHits7", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotOutput("pHits8", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotOutput("pHits9", width = 500, height = 500),
                          plotOutput("pHits10", width = 500, height = 500)
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
  
  plot_data <- eventReactive(input$pHitsMake, {
    inputData <- input$pHitsFile
    d <- read.csv(inputData$datapath)
    source("pHitsMaker.R")
    out <- pHits(d)
    out
  })
  output$pHits1 <- renderPlotly(
    {
      plot_data()$pqi
    }
  )
  output$pHits2 <- renderPlotly(
    {
      plot_data()$pqo
    }
  )
  output$pHits3 <- renderPlotly(
    {
      plot_data()$pqci
    }
  )
  output$pHits4 <- renderPlotly(
    {
      plot_data()$pqco
    }
  )
  output$pHits5 <- renderPlot(
    {
      plot_data()$pqci_padrow
      
    }
  )
  output$pHits6 <- renderPlot(
    {
      plot_data()$pqco_padrow
      
    }
  )
  output$pHits7 <- renderPlot(
    {
      plot_data()$pqci_agg
      
    }
  )
  output$pHits8 <- renderPlot(
    {
      plot_data()$pqco_agg
      
    }
  )
  output$pHits9 <- renderPlot(
    {
      plot_data()$pfitd0
      
    }
  )
  output$pHits10 <- renderPlot(
    {
      plot_data()$pfitd1
      
    }
  )
}

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.